# Trigger to input sub-subfolder names from Google Drive into Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, button, triggers, google-drive-api

## **My goal is to:**

**Create a trigger** to automatically **input/update the names of sub-subfolders** as **a cell in google sheets** in a google drive folder every time **a change happens in the gdrive folder** i.e. a folder/file is uploaded to the gdrive folder,

The trigger will automatically execute multiple functions as provided below:

```
var folderId = 'folderId';

function listFolders(){
  getFolderTree(folderId, false);
};

function listAll(){
  getFolderTree(folderId, true); 
};

function getFolderTree(folderId, listAll) {
  try {
    var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);

    var file, data, sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Resources");
    sheet.clear('A1');
    sheet.appendRow(["Name"]);

    getChildFolders(parentFolder.getName(), parentFolder, data, sheet, listAll);

  } catch (e) {
    Logger.log(e.toString());
  }
};

function getChildFolders(parentName, parent, data, sheet, listAll) {
  var childFolders = parent.getFolders();

  while (childFolders.hasNext()) {
    var childFolder = childFolders.next();
    // Logger.log("Folder Name: " + childFolder.getName());
    data = [ 
      childFolder.getName()
    ];
    sheet.appendRow(data);

    var files = childFolder.getFiles();
    while (listAll & files.hasNext()) {
      var childFile = files.next();
      // Logger.log("File Name: " + childFile.getName());
      data = [ 
        parentName + "/" + childFolder.getName() + "/" + childFile.getName(),
        childFile.getName()
      ];
      // Write
      sheet.appendRow(data);
    }

    getChildFolders(parentName + "/" + childFolder.getName(), childFolder, data, sheet, listAll);  
  }
};

function appendToColumn() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Resources");
  var data = "End";
  //Get the column where you want to append the data
  var range = sheet.getRange("A1:A").getValues().flat();
  var row = range.filter(String).length;
  Logger.log(row);
  sheet.getRange(row+1,2).setValue(data);
}
```

My expected flow is as illustrated below:

[Folder gets uploaded to gdrive folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTm7D.png)
[Sub-subfolder preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kwnkk.png)
[Sub-subfolder names gets input to google sheets by trigger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKJ5u.png)

But I've yet to find a comprehensive answer for either installable or simple triggers.

Comment: `every time a change happens in the gdrive folder` There are no built-in triggers available for `Google Drive`. A work-around might be to use a `time-driven spreadsheet trigger` but I'm not quite certain how one would establish the nature of the a change in a specific folder. I guess you could collect a range of data and check for changes.

Comment: `Goal 2` - One issue per question. You may be best to post a new question or research existing answers to this issue.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.